# Error Send email from contact us page

Tags: magento2

When I send mail from contact us page on SUBMIT, following error was displayed.

> "Unable to send mail: Unknown error".

Please find below image

I am working in localhost with Magento 2.3. When I fill the form under the contact us page (myurl/contacts/), following error display.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please use any SMTP extension to send emails
Eg: [Abzer SMTP](https://marketplace.magento.com/abzertech-smtp.html)